# how to put the functionality of tweet button on a submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

[This is my site.](http://91.109.247.178/~buddreambig/bud.html)

At the bottom of the page, there is a tweet button and a submit button.

What I want to do is put the functionality of tweet button on submit button and then remove the tweet button.

```
         <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="https://www.buddreambig.ie/" data-text="Share your dream" data-hashtags="DreamBig"><!-- <img src="images/submit-button.png"> --></a>
                <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
                </script>

                <input type="image" src="images/submit-button.png" id="btn" class="twitter-share-button">
```

Answer (score 0):

my query is now resolved. this is what I did.

html

```
                    <img type="image" src="images/submit-button.png" id="sharesubmit" >
```

js

```
$("#sharesubmit").click(function() {
    console.log('WOOOO');
    window.open("http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + escape($('#comment').val() + " https://www.buddreambig.ie/ #DreamBig"), "twitter", "toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325");
});
```